# Java trying to read intention as an Integer string

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse the a data file. This code has worked successfully for my other data files; however, I'm now getting an error. These data files are indented therefore the computer is trying to read the first space. How would I skip over this space?

```
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {

    String[] parts = line.split(" ");

    if (linecounter != 0) {
        for (int j=0; j<parts.length; j++) {

            if (j==parts.length-1)
                truepartition.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[j]));
            else {
                tempvals.add(Double.parseDouble(parts[j]));
                numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(parts[j]));
            }
        }
        Points.add(tempvals);
        tempvals = new ArrayList<Double>();
    } else {
        //Initialize variables with values in the first line
        // Reads each elements in the text file into the program 1 by 1
        for (int i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
            if (i==0)
                numofpoints = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
            else if (i==1)
                dim = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]) - 1;
            else if (i==2)
                numofclus = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
        }
    }
    linecounter++;
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

```
Data File
     75 3 4
     4    53 0
     5    63 0
    10    59 0
```

Comment: Use your debugger! What error? Show its stacktrace! What is the expected output=?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at phase1.phase4.FileRead(phase4.java:240)
 at phase1.phase4.main(phase4.java:121)

Comment: Do you mean *indented*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This number format error is coming because you can't format space characters in the base 10.
I can see many extra whitespaces is there in your input, split(" ") this will not work.

So replace normal white space split with regex.
use the below code and it will take care of extra whitespaces in your input.

```
 String[] parts = line.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. Skips over spaces and aids in parsing files.

for example:

```
try {
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(new File("path/to/dataFile"));
    while(inp.hasNext()) {
        int value = inp.nextInt();
        System.out.println(value);

    }
    inp.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```